# Videos.js bypass embed video

Tags: video.js

Is it possible to bypass url link to my own-host name and get a video content from actual host like Vimeo by videojs.

where could i edit in .js file or something? I don't know how to do it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a vimeo plugin for videojs: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-vimeo

This lets you use videojs to show vimeo videos.